# Required Hardware for Solana Node with Historical Transaction Info Enabled

Tags: rpc, validator, node

I've reviewed the hardware requirements listed on the official Solana site for running a node, particularly one with historical transaction info enabled via JSON RPC. However, I'm concerned the information might be out-of-date.

Could anyone provide the latest specifications or personal recommendations for:

- **CPU:** What kind of processing power should I aim for?
- **RAM:** Minimum and recommended memory?
- **SSD:** What storage specs are needed for the transaction history?
- **Network:** Required bandwidth and latency?

I'm particularly interested in any additional requirements that historical transaction queries may impose.

Any recommendations or references to recent guidelines would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [official recommendations](https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/requirements) might be a little outdated, they still are pretty accurate in terms of hardware requirements. For your cpu, you want a high clock speed AMD CPU with at least 16 cores. The 7443p and 9274F are good options.

RAM Is fully dependent on what accounts you want your RPC to index. If all you need is historical TX info, 256 GB is likely enough. On the other hand, if you want your RPC to index everything, you will need 1 TB+ of RAM.

For disks, 2x 2TB NVMe's should be fine.

You can expect your node to use upwards of 300 TB of bandwidth a month.

Make sure you pass `--enable-rpc-transaction-history` as a startup argument

Comment: Im using AMD EPYC 9354P , 380G RAM , 8T nvme, Network 1 GBit . everything is working well just for a few hours, but after 1 or 2 hours, I see more than 1k slots are behind. Im not using any account-index. Just I want to be stable validator first .

Comment: This could be caused my multiple things. For instance, your rpc could be hit by bots. To solve this, enable firewall. Also try setting your cpu cores to performance mode by doing: echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor